# How to run ClientScript in User Control?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I am using the code:

```
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "message", message);
```

This code works fine in an ASP.NET page but does not in a UserControl. I need to use this functionality in UserControl.

Comment: `typeof(Page)`? May be catch is here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try:

```
    string script = "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('hello');</script>";
    Page.RegisterStartupScript("myscript", script);
```

or

```
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", "<script>alert('Hello.')</script>", false);
```

Comment: I realise this is an old answer, but this is now, in 2015, an obsolete way to add script, you should use this instead : Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myscript", script, true);

Answer (score 4):

I use this in my user controls:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "message", message)
```